# gsutil fails with "OSError: Operation not permitted" when running from cron

Tags: php, cron, gsutil

I have a php script that does backups. The backups have been failing, because one of the first commands throws an error and stops the script. When I run the script in the terminal, it works just fine. I even set up the cron to run at the next minute, so I know the machine is active, the external hard drive is mounted and accessible, etc, but then it still fails.

This is the command I'm executing:

> /Users/kenny/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil cp
> gs://backups.mydomain.com/sql/mydomain-db.2023-06-17-1687023004.sql.gz
> /Users/kenny/extdrive/backup.mydomain/backups/2023/sql/2023-06-17/mydomain-db.2023-06-17-1687023004.sql.gz
> 2>&1

And my logs show:

> Copying
> gs://backups.herdboss.com/sql/herdboss-db.2023-06-17-1687023004.sql.gz...
>
> ==> NOTE: You are downloading one or more large file(s), which would
> run significantly faster if you enabled sliced object downloads. This
> feature is enabled by default but requires that compiled crcmod be
> installed (see "gsutil help crcmod").
>
> OSError: Operation not permitted.
>
> ERROR: COMMAND EXIT CODE: 1

One potential clue, is that I checked on the message about crcmod needing to be enabled to help the download speed, but I've already got crcmod installed. I followed the instructions from `gsutil help crcmod` and it said the configuration was good.

I'm not sure if that helps identify the problem, but there does seem to be at least some environmental difference when I run from cron vs run from the command line.

Any ideas?

---

If it matters, here is the php that I use the run the command:

```
$cmd = "$gsutil cp $gspath $backupdir/$filename";
execandlog($cmd);


function execandlog(string $command, string $inputtext = null, bool $shouldhorkonerrorexitcode = true, int &$exitcode = null): ?string {
    $fullcommand = "$command 2>&1";
    logmesg($fullcommand);
    
    $descriptors = [
        0 => ($inputtext === null) ? STDIN : ['pipe', 'r'],
        1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
        2 => STDERR,
    ];
    
    $pipes = [];    
    $process = proc_open($fullcommand, $descriptors, $pipes);
    $output = null;
    
    if (is_resource($process)) {
        if ($inputtext !== null) {
            if (false === fwrite($pipes[0], $inputtext)) {
                logmesg("ERROR: UNABLE TO WRITE TEXT TO INPUT PIPE");
                exit(-1);
            }
            
            fclose($pipes[0]);
        }
        
        $output = '';
        $commandoutputstream = $pipes[1];
        while (false === feof($commandoutputstream)) {
            $line = trim(fgets($commandoutputstream, 4096));
            $output .= "$line\n";
            logmesg($line);
        }
        fclose($commandoutputstream);
        
        $status = proc_get_status($process);
        $exitcode = $status['exitcode'];
        proc_close($process);
        
        if ($exitcode !== 0) {
            // Something went wrong
            logmesg("ERROR: COMMAND EXIT CODE: $exitcode");
            if ($shouldhorkonerrorexitcode) {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $output;
}
```